# Drupal link append re-direct url

Tags: redirect, module, hyperlink, drupal-7

I am using the following code to create a link to the create user page:

> l('create new user', 'admin/people/create');

It works perfectly but **is there a way to include a destination with the function so when the submit button is clicked it returns my user to the page of origin?**

I am attempting to accomplish it with the following code:

> $link = l('create new user',
>   'admin/people/create&destination=group/node/5/admin/people/add-user');

but when I click my link get sent to **admin/people** which means the first part of the process has already failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
l('create new user', 'admin/people/create', array('query' => array('destination' => 'group/node/5/admin/people/add-user')))
```